# How to customize PlaceAutocomplete widget dialog design to list places

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places-api

I need to show a list of places in `dropdown` using google `placeAutocomplete` widgets. Here I'm getting dialog to show places according to my query but I need to give a custom design for that search result dialog as in Uber, Ola apps. Here I want a design like the below image. If anyone has done this before please give me your suggestions, thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to customize your adapter. I had implemented this functionality in my project. You can follow this.

> activity_search.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/search_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/searchbar_bg"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_margin_10"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_margin_10"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_margin_10"
            android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/search_et"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:hint="Search"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/clear"
                        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_search"
                        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/activity_margin_10"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_margin_10"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_margin_10"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/clear"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_clear"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                        android:padding="@dimen/activity_margin_16"
                        android:visibility="gone"/>
                </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/search_layout"
            android:layout_above="@+id/powered_by_google"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_margin_10"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/powered_by_google"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_margin_10"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_margin_10"
            android:src="@drawable/powered_by_google_light"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

> SearchActivity.java

```
package com.android.dezi.views.rider.Activities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.dezi.BaseActivity;
import com.android.dezi.R;
import com.android.dezi.adapters.PlaceAutocompleteAdapter;
import com.android.dezi.adapters.PlaceAutocompleteAdapter.PlaceAutoCompleteInterface;
import com.android.dezi.adapters.PlaceSavedAdapter;
import com.android.dezi.adapters.PlaceSavedAdapter.SavedPlaceListener;
import com.android.dezi.beans.SavedAddress;
import com.android.dezi.views.rider.Fragments.SearchFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocomplete;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by anuj.sharma on 4/6/2016.
 */
public class SearchActivity extends BaseActivity implements PlaceAutoCompleteInterface, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,OnClickListener,SavedPlaceListener {
    Context mContext;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    LinearLayout mParent;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    LinearLayoutManager llm;
    PlaceAutocompleteAdapter mAdapter;
    List<SavedAddress> mSavedAddressList;
    PlaceSavedAdapter mSavedAdapter;
    private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_INDIA = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(-0, 0), new LatLng(0, 0));

    EditText mSearchEdittext;
    ImageView mClear;

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_search);
        mContext = SearchActivity.this;

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, 0 /* clientId */, this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .build();

        initViews();
    }

    /*
   Initialize Views
    */
    private void initViews(){
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.list_search);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        llm = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

        mSearchEdittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.search_et);
        mClear = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.clear);
        mClear.setOnClickListener(this);

        mAdapter = new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.view_placesearch,
                mGoogleApiClient, BOUNDS_INDIA, null);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mSearchEdittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (count > 0) {
                    mClear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (mAdapter != null) {
                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    }
                } else {
                    mClear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if (mSavedAdapter != null && mSavedAddressList.size() > 0) {
                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mSavedAdapter);
                    }
                }
                if (!s.toString().equals("") && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    mAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                } else if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
//                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Constants.API_NOT_CONNECTED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("", "NOT CONNECTED");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == mClear){
            mSearchEdittext.setText("");
            if(mAdapter!=null){
                mAdapter.clearList();
            }

        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPlaceClick(ArrayList<PlaceAutocompleteAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete> mResultList, int position) {
        if(mResultList!=null){
            try {
                final String placeId = String.valueOf(mResultList.get(position).placeId);
                        /*
                             Issue a request to the Places Geo Data API to retrieve a Place object with additional details about the place.
                         */

                PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                        .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
                placeResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
                        if(places.getCount()==1){
                            //Do the things here on Click.....
                            Intent data = new Intent();
                            data.putExtra("lat",String.valueOf(places.get(0).getLatLng().latitude));
                            data.putExtra("lng", String.valueOf(places.get(0).getLatLng().longitude));
                            setResult(SearchActivity.RESULT_OK, data);
                            finish();
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"something went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e){

            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSavedPlaceClick(List<SavedAddress> mResponse, int position) {
        if(mResponse!=null){
            try {
                Intent data = new Intent();
                data.putExtra("lat",String.valueOf(mResponse.get(position).getLatitude()));
                data.putExtra("lng", String.valueOf(mResponse.get(position).getLongitude()));
                setResult(SearchActivity.RESULT_OK, data);
                finish();
            }
            catch (Exception e){

            }

        }
    }
}
```

> PlaceAutocompleteAdapter.java

This is customized adapter. All important part is inside this.

```
package com.android.dezi.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.style.CharacterStyle;
import android.text.style.StyleSpan;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.dezi.R;
import com.android.dezi.beans.TripHistoryBean;
import com.android.dezi.views.rider.Fragments.SearchFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataBufferUtils;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePrediction;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePredictionBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Created by anuj.sharma on 4/6/2016.
 */
public class PlaceAutocompleteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlaceAutocompleteAdapter.PlaceViewHolder> implements Filterable{

    public interface PlaceAutoCompleteInterface{
        public void onPlaceClick(ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> mResultList, int position);
    }

    Context mContext;
    PlaceAutoCompleteInterface mListener;
    private static final String TAG = "PlaceAutocompleteAdapter";
    private static final CharacterStyle STYLE_BOLD = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
    ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> mResultList;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private LatLngBounds mBounds;

    private int layout;

    private AutocompleteFilter mPlaceFilter;


    public PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, int resource, GoogleApiClient googleApiClient,
                                    LatLngBounds bounds, AutocompleteFilter filter){
        this.mContext = context;
        layout = resource;
        mGoogleApiClient = googleApiClient;
        mBounds = bounds;
        mPlaceFilter = filter;
        this.mListener = (PlaceAutoCompleteInterface)mContext;
    }

    /*
    Clear List items
     */
    public void clearList(){
        if(mResultList!=null && mResultList.size()>0){
            mResultList.clear();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Sets the bounds for all subsequent queries.
     */
    public void setBounds(LatLngBounds bounds) {
        mBounds = bounds;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                // Skip the autocomplete query if no constraints are given.
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Query the autocomplete API for the (constraint) search string.
                    mResultList = getAutocomplete(constraint);
                    if (mResultList != null) {
                        // The API successfully returned results.
                        results.values = mResultList;
                        results.count = mResultList.size();
                    }
                }
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    // The API returned at least one result, update the data.
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    // The API did not return any results, invalidate the data set.
                    //notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }

    private ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> getAutocomplete(CharSequence constraint) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Log.i("", "Starting autocomplete query for: " + constraint);

            // Submit the query to the autocomplete API and retrieve a PendingResult that will
            // contain the results when the query completes.
            PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results =
                    Places.GeoDataApi
                            .getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, constraint.toString(),
                                    mBounds, mPlaceFilter);

            // This method should have been called off the main UI thread. Block and wait for at most 60s
            // for a result from the API.
            AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictions = results
                    .await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            // Confirm that the query completed successfully, otherwise return null
            final Status status = autocompletePredictions.getStatus();
            if (!status.isSuccess()) {
//                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error contacting API: " + status.toString(),
//                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("", "Error getting autocomplete prediction API call: " + status.toString());
                autocompletePredictions.release();
                return null;
            }

            Log.i("", "Query completed. Received " + autocompletePredictions.getCount()
                    + " predictions.");

            // Copy the results into our own data structure, because we can't hold onto the buffer.
            // AutocompletePrediction objects encapsulate the API response (place ID and description).

            Iterator<AutocompletePrediction> iterator = autocompletePredictions.iterator();
            ArrayList resultList = new ArrayList<>(autocompletePredictions.getCount());
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                AutocompletePrediction prediction = iterator.next();
                // Get the details of this prediction and copy it into a new PlaceAutocomplete object.
                resultList.add(new PlaceAutocomplete(prediction.getPlaceId(),
                        prediction.getDescription()));
            }

            // Release the buffer now that all data has been copied.
            autocompletePredictions.release();

            return resultList;
        }
        Log.e("", "Google API client is not connected for autocomplete query.");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public PlaceViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(layout, viewGroup, false);
        PlaceViewHolder mPredictionHolder = new PlaceViewHolder(convertView);
        return mPredictionHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PlaceViewHolder mPredictionHolder, final int i) {
        mPredictionHolder.mAddress.setText(mResultList.get(i).description);

        mPredictionHolder.mParentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mListener.onPlaceClick(mResultList,i);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(mResultList != null)
            return mResultList.size();
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public PlaceAutocomplete getItem(int position) {
        return mResultList.get(position);
    }

    /*
    View Holder For Trip History
     */
    public class PlaceViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //        CardView mCardView;
        public RelativeLayout mParentLayout;
        public TextView mAddress;

        public PlaceViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mParentLayout = (RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.predictedRow);
            mAddress = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.address);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Holder for Places Geo Data Autocomplete API results.
     */
    public class PlaceAutocomplete {

        public CharSequence placeId;
        public CharSequence description;

        PlaceAutocomplete(CharSequence placeId, CharSequence description) {
            this.placeId = placeId;
            this.description = description;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return description.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

> view_placesearch.xml

Customized view that you want to show in your adapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/predictedRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_navigate"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        />
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/light_gray"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it will help you too.

**Note:**
Do not forget to add API key in your `manifest` file.

**Output will be like:**

[image]

I found some Useful links that can also help you.

**[1. Android Plat Places using custom Adapter](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places)**

Comment: `getDescription()` of `AutocompletePrediction` is now deprecated.

Comment: Hi @AnujSharma it is being crashed if type very fastly  on edit text and below i will post the error please see once }
 Process: com.jugaad.customer, PID: 20267
                                                                     java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 0
                                                                         at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                         at

Comment: @RajKumar: thanks for mentioning this. I will check this and update my answer.

Comment: Ok @AnujSharma thank you and do u want me to post my placeadapterclass

Comment: @RajKumar: Yeah sure this is open community, anybody can answer. You can post your answer, it could help other developers for sure.

Comment: @AnujSharma Please add SavedPlaceListener ,PlaceSavedAdapter and SavedAddress

Comment: @RajKumar, any solution to the  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Comment: Hi @Stone Cold nothing  /**You just need to create new object then crash problem 
                 will not occur**/
                mResultList = new ArrayList<>;
you can find below answer post by me

Comment: @AnujSharma please add PlaceSavedAdapter,SavedPlaceListener and SavedAddress

Comment: please add PlaceSavedAdapter,SavedPlaceListener and SavedAddress

Comment: Here is SavedAddress.java & SavdPlaceListner.java

public class SavedAddress {
    String Latitude, Longitude;

    public String getLatitude() {
        return Latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        Latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return Longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        Longitude = longitude;
    }
}

*******************************
public interface SavedPlaceListener {
    public void onSavedPlaceClick(ArrayList<SavedAddress> mResultList, int position);
}

Comment: too late but i found good way fir it  -https://github.com/jotaramirez90/AutocompleteLocation

Comment: How to get selected location latlong values?

Comment: @AnujSharma Thank you so much for the solution. But I want to implement this functionality in a **Fragment**. When I try to use it in a fragment app crashes saying

**com.solequick.Activities.ClientHome Activity cannot be cast to com.solequick.Adapters.PlaceAutocompleteAdapter$PlaceAutoComplete Interface**

Answer (score 1):

In view of the latest changes in the AutocompletePrediction API, here is the revised Adapter and Filter code:

**PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter.java**

```
package com.equinox.prologix.Adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.equinox.prologix.Activities.LocationChooseActivity;
import com.equinox.prologix.Filters.PlaceAutoCompleteFilter;
import com.equinox.prologix.R;
import com.equinox.prologix.ViewHolders.PlaceAutoCompleteHolder;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePrediction;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.GeoDataClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceBufferResponse;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocomplete;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Mohammed Mukhtar on 12/1/2017.
 */

public class PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlaceAutoCompleteHolder> implements Filterable {

    private Context context;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private PlaceAutoCompleteFilter placeAutoCompleteFilter;
    private GeoDataClient mGeoDataClient;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private Handler autoCompleteSelected;
    private List<AutocompletePrediction> resultPlaceList;

    public PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, GoogleApiClient googleApiClient, List<AutocompletePrediction> resultPlaceList, Handler autoCompleteSelected) {
        this.context = context;
        this.resultPlaceList = resultPlaceList;
        this.googleApiClient = googleApiClient;
        this.autoCompleteSelected = autoCompleteSelected;
        mGeoDataClient = Places.getGeoDataClient(context, null);
    }

    @Override
    public PlaceAutoCompleteHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_google_place_autocomplete, parent, false);
        return new PlaceAutoCompleteHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PlaceAutoCompleteHolder holder, final int position) {
        final AutocompletePrediction autocompletePrediction = resultPlaceList.get(position);
        holder.getLocationAddressView().setText(autocompletePrediction.getPrimaryText(null));
        holder.getLocationLocalityView().setText(autocompletePrediction.getSecondaryText(null));
        holder.getItemView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mGeoDataClient.getPlaceById(autocompletePrediction.getPlaceId()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<PlaceBufferResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<PlaceBufferResponse> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            PlaceBufferResponse places = task.getResult();
                            Place myPlace = places.get(0);
                            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myPlace.getLatLng(), 17));
                            autoCompleteSelected.sendMessage(Message.obtain());
                            Log.i("getPlaceById", "Place found: " + myPlace.getName());
                            places.release();
                        } else Log.e("getPlaceById", "Place not found.");
                    }
                });
                Toast.makeText(context, resultPlaceList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getFullText(null), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return resultPlaceList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (placeAutoCompleteFilter == null)
            placeAutoCompleteFilter = new PlaceAutoCompleteFilter(googleApiClient, this, resultPlaceList);
        return placeAutoCompleteFilter;
    }

    public void setGoogleMap(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.googleMap = googleMap;
    }
}
```

**PlaceAutoCompleteFilter.java**

```
package com.equinox.prologix.Filters;

import android.text.style.CharacterStyle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Filter;

import com.equinox.prologix.Adapters.PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePrediction;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePredictionBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocomplete;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static com.equinox.prologixappcommon.Models.DataHolderCommon.currentCountry;
import static com.equinox.prologixappcommon.Models.DataHolderCommon.currentLocation;
import static com.equinox.prologixappcommon.Utils.BackendTransform.transform;
import static com.equinox.prologixappcommon.Utils.BackendTransform.transform2;
import static com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_NONE;

/**
 * Created by Mohammed Mukhtar on 12/1/2017.
 */

public class PlaceAutoCompleteFilter extends Filter {

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter placeAutoCompleteAdapter;
    private List<AutocompletePrediction> resultPlaceList;

    public PlaceAutoCompleteFilter(GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient,
                                   PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter placeAutoCompleteAdapter,
                                   List<AutocompletePrediction> resultPlaceList) {
        this.mGoogleApiClient = mGoogleApiClient;
        this.placeAutoCompleteAdapter = placeAutoCompleteAdapter;
        this.resultPlaceList = resultPlaceList;
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        // Skip the autocomplete query if no constraints are given.
        if (constraint != null) {
            // Query the autocomplete API for the (constraint) search string.
            List<AutocompletePrediction> tempResult = getAutoComplete(constraint);
            if (tempResult != null) {
                results.values = tempResult;
                results.count = tempResult.size();
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
            resultPlaceList.clear();
            resultPlaceList.addAll((List<AutocompletePrediction>) results.values);
            placeAutoCompleteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else {
            // The API did not return any results, invalidate the data set.

        }
    }

    private ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> getAutoComplete(CharSequence constraint) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Log.i("", "Starting autocomplete query for: " + constraint);

            AutocompleteFilter autocompleteFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                    //.setCountry(currentCountry.getCountryCode())
                    .setTypeFilter(TYPE_FILTER_NONE)
                    .build();

            // Submit the query to the autocomplete API and retrieve a PendingResult that will
            // contain the results when the query completes.
            PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results =
                    Places.GeoDataApi
                            .getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, constraint.toString(),
                                    new LatLngBounds.Builder().include(transform(currentLocation)).build(),
                                    autocompleteFilter);

            // This method should have been called off the main UI thread. Block and wait for at most 60s
            // for a result from the API.
            AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictions = results.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            // Confirm that the query completed successfully, otherwise return null
            final Status status = autocompletePredictions.getStatus();
            if (!status.isSuccess()) {
//                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error contacting API: " + status.toString(),
//                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("", "Error getting autocomplete prediction API call: " + status.toString());
                autocompletePredictions.release();
                return null;
            }

            Log.i("", "Query completed. Received " + autocompletePredictions.getCount()
                    + " predictions.");

            // Copy the results into our own data structure, because we can't hold onto the buffer.
            // AutocompletePrediction objects encapsulate the API response (place ID and description).

            Iterator<AutocompletePrediction> iterator = autocompletePredictions.iterator();
            ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> resultList = new ArrayList<>(autocompletePredictions.getCount());
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                AutocompletePrediction prediction = iterator.next();
                resultList.add(prediction.freeze());
            }

            // Release the buffer now that all data has been copied.
            autocompletePredictions.release();

            return resultList;
        }
        Log.e("", "Google API client is not connected for autocomplete query.");
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**kotlin:**

```
fun queryPlaces(text: String) {
    val task = object : AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Void? {
            val results = Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, text, null, null)
            val autocompletePredictions = results.await()
            val iterator = autocompletePredictions.iterator()
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                val prediction = iterator.next()
                println("PlaceId:${prediction.placeId}")
                println("PrimaryText:${prediction.getPrimaryText(null)}")
            }
            autocompletePredictions.release()
            return null
        }
    }
    task.execute()
}
```

**If you want get the Place detail:**

```
fun queryPlaces(text: String) {
    val geoDataClient : GeoDataClient = Places.getGeoDataClient(context!!)

    val task = object : AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Void? {
            val results = Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, text, null, null)
            val autocompletePredictions = results.await()
            val iterator = autocompletePredictions.iterator()
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                val prediction = iterator.next()

                geoDataClient.getPlaceById(prediction.placeId).addOnCompleteListener {task->
                    val places = task.result
                    val myPlace = places?.get(0)
                    println("name:${myPlace?.name}")
                    println("latLng:${myPlace?.latLng}")
                    println("address:${myPlace?.address}")
                }
            }
            autocompletePredictions.release()
            return null
        }
    }
    task.execute()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create new arraylist every time in filter object

```
@Override 
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override 
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            // Skip the autocomplete query if no constraints are given. 
            if (constraint != null) {
                // Query the autocomplete API for the (constraint) search string. 

               /**You just need to create new object then crash problem 
                 will not occur**/
                mResultList = new ArrayList<>;

                mResultList = getAutocomplete(constraint);
                if (mResultList != null) {
                    // The API successfully returned results. 
                    results.values = mResultList;
                    results.count = mResultList.size();
                } 
            } 
            return results;
        } 

        @Override 
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                // The API returned at least one result, update the data. 
                notifyDataSetChanged(); 
            } else { 
                // The API did not return any results, invalidate the data set. 
                //notifyDataSetInvalidated(); 
            } 
        } 
    }; 
    return filter;
}
```

Comment: In context of what Activity / Fragment should one do this getFilter override?