# android - add button to auto complete search box

Tags: android, google-places-api

I have implemented Google's `PlaceAutocompleteFragment` in my android app and it looks like this below.
[image]

But I want to add a button in the end just how google maps has a microphone.

[image]

Below is my code so far:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Place select Code:

```
autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            String placeName = place.getName().toString();
            LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(placeName));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        }
        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });
```

A sample code would be nice. Thank you so much :)

Comment: will you add you seach code

Comment: I just did, can you pls take another look :)

Comment: I am looking at it and testing it on my android studio now, just give me time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very sorry about being so late to reply, but I have reinstalled and downloaded the whole Android Studio and the SDK because of some errors

Here is my suggestions to you :-

1. To use 3rd library [FloatingSearchView](https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview)
2. To customize you self but that will take some time respectively to the 3rd library and here are the easy tutorials that will helps you [Custom Google Place Autocomplete Android](http://www.techstricks.com/custom-google-place-autocomplete-android/) and [How to customize PlaceAutocomplete widget dialog design to list places Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999647/how-to-customize-placeautocomplete-widget-dialog-design-to-list-places)
3. Is to try enter deeper in Google's code to customize it knowing that this will be made by extending Google's class and copying the whole code of Google's then editing it is a Regenerated class

   Also the last step I have reached deeper it the code was to know that this method is the method which creates the Google search

   ```
   private void zzzG() {
   int var1 = -1;
   try {
       Intent var2 = (new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(2)).setBoundsBias(this.zzaRk).setFilter(this.zzaRl).zzeq(this.editSearch.getText().toString()).zzig(1).build(this.getActivity());
       this.startActivityForResult(var2, 1);
   } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException var3) {
       var1 = var3.getConnectionStatusCode();
       Log.e("Places", "Could not open autocomplete activity", var3);
   } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException var4) {
       var1 = var4.errorCode;
       Log.e("Places", "Could not open autocomplete activity", var4);
   }
   if (var1 != -1) {
       GoogleApiAvailability var5 = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
       var5.showErrorDialogFragment(this.getActivity(), var1, 2);
   }}
   ```

   Also, give me a feedback if you have a problem of any of those solutions

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you very much for helping me out with this. I really appreciate it.

Comment: you are very welcome, and I am thier if you need any help :)

Comment: @DasserBasyouni Nice code bro, do you know how to make for google search not for google place ?

Comment: @Spritzig unfortunately no, I even totally forgot about the code in the answer. but I will get back to you here if i worked on a related project

Comment: @DasserBasyouni ahah the best thing I have heard today, no problem man thanks for getting time to answer me.