# How to customize Place Autocomplete on android

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm using [Place AutoComplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete) with the default UI :

[image]

But I want to create my own like Uber and Waze does, I found tuns of tutorials, but most of them are deprecated, some codes doesn't work anymore... like [this](https://sunny89blog.wordpress.com/2016/02/07/placeautocompletefragment-with-custom-ui/).

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999647/how-to-customize-placeautocomplete-widget-dialog-design-to-list-places