# How to change google place autoComplete activity background color

Tags: android, google-places-api, android-theme

I am using `Autocomplete.IntentBuilder` to launch google's AutoCompleteActivity. I want to change the blue search background to white. I know this color is using my activity theme's `colorPrimary`.

Of course I could change that to white, but I also have other component that use colorPrimary, like MaterialButtons that needs to be red.

I feel google places is too restrictive that using it requires me to change all other components's style. Is there any way I can continue to use AutoCompleteActivity and keep my colorPrimary?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#option_2_use_an_intent_to_launch_the_autocomplete_activity
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize PlaceAutocomplete widget dialog design to list places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999647/how-to-customize-placeautocomplete-widget-dialog-design-to-list-places)

Comment: @BroscR, thanks but that approach is implementing a new Activity with custom UI instead of using the AutoCompleteActivity google already provided, looking for a way to continue to use AutoCompleteActivity

Comment: [AutoCompleteDemo](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-places-demos/tree/main/demo-java/app/src/v3/java/com/example/placesdemo) If you examine these samples in google samples, I think it will help you.

Comment: @BabyishTank Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: @FSUWX2011 sorry i don't